How to correctly query Postgres database with type annotations using sqlx QueryBuilder?
I am trying to query Postgresql using sqlx QueryBuilder, but annotating the query has me completely stumped.
The relevant part of my code is:
let mut builder = query_builder::QueryBuilder::new("WITH full_results AS (");

builder.push(r#"
    SELECT
        id,
        subscriber_id,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        plan_id,
        postage_id,
        amount,
        copies,
        delivery_type,
        payment_received_date,
        payment_instrument_date,
        payment_instrument,
        payment_instrument_details,
        payment_details,
        receipt_number
    FROM subscriptions
    WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
"#);

match subscriber {
    Some(subscriber_id) => {
        builder.push(" AND subscriber_id = ");
        builder.push_bind(subscriber_id);
    }
    None => {
        builder.push(if active { " AND end_date >= " } else { " AND end_date < " });
        builder.push_bind(end_date);
    }
};

builder.push(r#"
),
subset_results AS (
    SELECT * FROM full_results
"#);

builder.push(" ORDER BY end_date DESC");
builder.push(" LIMIT ");
builder.push_bind(limit);
builder.push(" OFFSET ");
builder.push_bind(offset);
builder.push(r#"
)
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM full_results) AS total_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subset_results) AS returned_count,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS "timestamp: DateTime<Utc>",
    array_agg(subset_results) AS "data: Vec<Subscription>"
FROM subset_results
"#);

let query = builder.build_query_as::<ResponseEnvelope::<Vec<Subscription>>>();

// log::info!("{:?}", &query.sql());

let subscriptions = query.fetch_one(pool.get_ref()).await;

After some debugging, I found that the "timestamp: <DateTime<Utc>>" and "data: Vec<Subscription>" are returned as Postgres RECORD type without casting to the annotated types and the column names are taken verbatim from the quoted annotation string. However, a very similar query using the same annotation style run through the query_as! macro returns correctly.
Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

I'm pretty sure only the macro-based API supports those annotations, since they need to be parsed at compile time.
